# Python, How to round up to maximum precision

Tags: python, rounding

It's quite a simple question actually, let's say i have this number 1.499998499999999e-98, now if i wanted to round it up to ~1.5e-98 how would i go about it? I tried the round() but it gives me 0.0 which is kind of useless for what i'm working on.

Comment: Just check your typing, as 1.49...e-83 wouldn't round up to 1.5e-98.

Comment: Do you want to round it for calculation or viewing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (kinda 'hacky') way would be to format the number as a string and convert back to float:

```
>>> x = 1.499998499999999e-98
>>> "%.2e" % x
'1.50e-98'
>>> float("%.2e" % x)
1.5e-98
```

Other than using `round`, this will round to *significant* digits, not "absolute" number of digits.

Comment: Hmm, it takes a bit of precision out of it but it works quite well for the work i'm doing, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of digits that you want to round to ([see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)), and also read the note about rounding being surprising.

[Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/index.html) may give you a little more control over [rounding](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around).